# Implementing Entity Framework for Simple Data Entry App

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

This has probably already been asked and answered 1000 times, but Google has not been not my friend this morning.

I'm making the switch from using stored procedures and business objects to using Entity Framework.  I like the simplicity of generating your POCOs from the generated EDM (Database-First approach here). And I like how much less typing it is.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around a suitable design for a VERY COMMON application scenario (in my world, anyway).

Basically, picture a data entry application, let's say for an online store's administrator (I'm doing it in WPF, but it could easily be web-based).

The admin will want to view a list of Customers (Manage Customers view) in a data grid. For each row, there is  button to edit the Customer or delete it.  At the bottom of the grid there is a button to create a new Customer.

If they delete a Customer, it is removed (after a confirmation) immediately from the data grid, as well as the back-end data store. If they edit a Customer, a window pops up (Edit Customer View), displaying the current data for that Customer.  They can edit the data, then click either Submit, or Cancel.  Submit saves the changes to the data store, and cancel discards the changes. Both buttons close the Window.

If, they click the New Customer button from the Manage Customer view, then a new Customer object is created (not saved to the DB yet), and the same Edit Customer view is opened, displaying the new, blank Customer.

Here is what I've got so far:

When the Manage Customers View Model is constructed, it populates a public list of Customers, something like:

```
public List<Customer> customers {get; set; }  
using (WebStoreEndities context = new WebStoreEntities())
{
    customers = context.Customers.ToList();
}
```

Then, if the admin user clicks the Edit button in a Customer row, the bound Customer object is passed to the constructor of the Edit Customer view. That view constructs its view model, which has the customer property that the view is bound to.  The user can make their changes to the Customer object in the view, then either click Save or Cancel.

This is where I get lost.  In my business object/stored procedure implementation, I would just have two Customer objects: one for the Customer being edited (bound to the view), and one copy of that Customer, called backupCustomer, used for reverting changes if they cancel out of the Edit Customer view (since I'm using MVVM, the properties of the Customer are changed immediately from the UI, and if they start making changes, and then click Cancel, they'll expect not to see their changes in that Customer).

More to the point, if they do click Submit in the Edit Customer view, that calls the Customer business object's Save() method, which reaches into the DAL and fires off the stored procedure to update the data store.

Okay, so now on to Entity Framework reality.

Issue #1.  There is no way to save an individual entity.  So even if I extend the Customer entity to have a Save() method, it would have to create a new WebStoreEntities context and call SaveChanges() on it:

```
using (WebStoreEntities context = new WebStoreEntities())
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

That seems weird to me.  I wouldn't think you'd want have an entity instance creating entity contexts and stuff.

Issue #2. In my business objects implementation, I cache my objects, so I only need to ever fetch them from the DB once.  If they make changes to a Customer, great.  I just call save() on it and it updates the data store.  Same with deletes and inserts.  But I never have to fetch the same collection of Customers more than once (concurrency is not an issue on this particular project).  In my EF implementation, every time they open the Manage Customers view, it's firing off the code above to get a list of Customers.  I suppose I could just keep one data context open during the entire application, but that seems like a bad design too.  Tying up a connection the the data store for the entire user session, just because they might open the same view more than once.

Please help me with my above issues, if you can, don't get hung up on what I'm about to say (it's just my initial impression anyway):

It seems like EF muddies the logical boundaries in my separation of concerns:

- You have to keep a copy of the Entity connection string in your UI project (I keep my business objects and data objects in a separate project usually).
- You can't tell an entity to save itself or delete itself.  You have to do it from the underlying context, which is typically in the UI layer.  In my UI, I like to be able to say myBusinessObject.Save() or myBusinessObject.Delete(), knowing that the object knows how to save or delete itself.

Anyway, it seems like EF is the future, so I'm going to stick with it.  I would love your recommendations.

Thanks so much!

The Funk Monkey.

Comment: Check out the Repository and Unit of Work pattern for using EF. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/688929/Repository-Pattern-and-Unit-of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While most examples have you implement queries surrounded by a `using` you shouldn't actually do that in your case. Each EF context tracks it's own entity changes, by using multiple `using`s you won't know which context did the look up to call `SaveChanges` on it. So just use one context per user and dispose when your completely done (on exit, ect). You can use a singleton or a static class, in a desktop app it doesn't seem to make much difference from my experience. In an MVVM scenario you may be able to get away with the ViewModel handling the context as well, so when you instantiate your ViewModel instantiate your context and dispose your context on dispose, that might make more logical sense depending on how your handle the data internally.

For being able to revert changes EF actually tracks both the original DB version of the object as well as your changed version of the object. However to get that information is a little convoluted:

Disconnect and look up the entity:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)myContext).ObjectContext.Detach(dbObject);
var entry = myContext.Entry(dbObject);
var original = entry.OriginalValues;
```

Personally I just handle copying and keeping the original object in code, it's cleaner and seems to be safer. It's also probably faster, but I've never run tests to prove that. If you're in a multi-user environment you may benefit from simply reloading the data from the DB though so that you don't mistakenly display stale data.

Comment: Thanks.  I wound up going this route, it made the most sense for my purposes.  It's working really well!  Thanks everyone for your help. For whatever reason, marking this response as the answer isn't working.  Maybe SO dislikes Safari.  Anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Issue #1: You want you entity to have a `Save` method but you want to avoid creating a coupling between the entity and the persistence layer (e.g. the EF context)? Well, if the `Save` method is implemented by the entity then you cannot avoid that. Better perhaps, is to move the `Save` method to a repository:

```
repository.Update(entity);
```

Now it is the responsibility of the repository to create the EF context, not the entity.

Issue #2: EF contexts are lightweight and the normal pattern of usage is as you describe where the context is created transiently and then disposed after changes have been saved. Conceivably, you can create a desktop app the has one context for the lifetime of the application but if the database is changed while the app is running the content of the context will get out of date. Sooner or later inconsistency in state will hit you and I would think that you get a more maintainable application if you stick to the transient context pattern. If you are writing a web app you will not have the option to keep a database context alive between requests and that pattern has proven to be very successful when writing business apps.

So I recommend this:

- Implement persistence in a repository or service class, not in the entity class.
- When reading or writing entities do it in a manner that ensures that the EF context only exists for the duration of the operation (unit of work). Optionally, you can use a row version number to ensure that an entity cannot be updated if it has been changed in the database after the last write.

Answer (score 0):

By the sounds of it...you prefer the ActiveRecord pattern...but EF follows the UnitOfWork pattern...in your case you are using POCO Entities....which are "persistent-ignorant".

- http://randolphcabral.wordpress.com/2008/04/03/active-record-vs-unit-of-work/
- [refactoring: swicthing from custom data access layer to Entity Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7525594/refactoring-swicthing-from-custom-data-access-layer-to-entity-framework)

One approach to hide the "EF technology", is to create a "repository" layer inside of which you hide all the EF logic i.e. management of the "context". But creating another layer can be a lot of repetitive work. Typically your repositories would share the same context.

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2013/08/23/using-repository-pattern-in-entity-framework.aspx
- http://www.dataworks.ie/blog/entity_framework_5_with_automapper_and_repository_pattern

If you keep the EF context around, then it manages the change-tracking and caching of already retrieved objects for you.

Alternatively, you can work in a disconnected mode...where you create the context each time you want to retrieve/perist entities...however, you then have to do the caching and state-tracking yourself and "reattach" the objects to the context, before submitting.